# Why does Generating Random Value from utils.js to React JS Component Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Let's say that a functional reactjs component tries to call an add
>   task function in utils.js

**utils.js**

```
const generateRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500)
    const obj = { isChecked: false, id: generateRandom() }
    const newTask = (name) => {
        return { ...obj, name }
    }

    const AddTask = (tasks, name) => [...tasks, newTask(name)]

module.exports={AddTask}
```

**ReactJs Component**

```
import {AddTask} from './utils.js'
```

**Issue**

> This line generates random value once which means all my tasks have got same id.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move object creation inside the newTask function:

```
const generateRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
const newTask = (name) => {
  const obj = { isChecked: false, id: generateRandom() };
  return { ...obj, name };
};

const AddTask = (tasks, name) => [...tasks, newTask(name)];

module.exports = { AddTask };
```

In my opinion, you should not generate ids like that instead use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or something similar.

Comment: and at that point, just put the 2 properties into the returned object directly instead of spreading them for no reason. `(tasks, name) => [...tasks, { isChecked: false, id: rand(), name }]`